# Uniform Limit of Nets Measurable?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Clearly, the pointwise limit of a *sequences* of measurable functions is measurable:
$$f_n\text{ measurable}\implies f\text{ measurable}\quad(f_n\to f\text{ pointwise})$$
(Especially, this holds true for uniform limit of a *sequence*.)

On the other hand this fails for *nets* in general, e.g.:
$$f_{E\in\mathcal{B}([0,1]):E\subseteq V}:=\chi_E:\quad f_E\text{ measurable},f\text{ nonmeasurable}$$
with a Vitali set $V$ of the unit interval $[0,1]$.

But what about the uniform limit of a *net*:
$$f_\lambda\text{ measurable}\implies f\text{ measurable}\quad(f_\lambda\to f\text{ uniformly})$$
This, especially, would imply that the bounded Borel functions form a Banach space under the supremum norm...

Comment: well I mean uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence

Comment: @Pelto: Yes, sure, but pointwise convergence of **nets** doesn't imply measurability.

Comment: To see that the bounded Borel functions form a Banach space, you do not need the measurability of (uniform) limits of nets, just that of sequences.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Ah right I forgot ^^ thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\{ f_{\alpha_{n}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\sup |f_{\alpha_{n}}-f| < 1/n$.